# Interface and abstract c# inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, interface, .net-core, abstract

I am encountering a problem with interfaces. I wish to chain a method which derives its chainable method from an abstract class, which implements an interface.

```
public interface IBaseInterface {
    public IBaseInterface ChainableMethod()
}

public abstract AbstractClassThatHelps<T> where T: IBaseInterface n {
    public T ChainableMethod() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}

public interface IDerived : IBaseInterface { }

public class DerivedClass : AbstractClassThatHelps<IDerived>, IDerived { }

IDerived derived =  new DerivedClass();
derived.ChainableMethod().ChainableMethod();
```

The problem I face here: why can't `T` be returned when it is shown to implement the contract IModel?

How would I solve this differently? I wish to have type safety but I am forced for all derived classes to return IBaseInterface instead of their own interface.

---

Actual implementation:
We have multiple models (`DerivedClass`'s) which implement their respective `IDerived` for dependency injection. These need helpers because i dont want to repeat myself.. So we use `AbstractClassThatHelps` as a base, but because we are dealing with chainable methods we need this base class to know what to return, so therefore generics. `IBaseInterface` can be seen as `IModel`. Where `ChainableMethod` can be seen as `GetAll()` for example.

Comment: because `AbstractClassThatHelps` doesn't inherit from `IBaseInterface`

Comment: whilst the above comments are correct about the return type being T. I would also suggest that you should make a post about what you are actually trying to achieve. because looking at the code above I would HIGHLY doubt this is the best way of solving whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry about my comments, there are so many things wrong with the code in the question that I got confused. @Konrad has the right comment for the question why `T` cannot be returned, the rest I'll just leave be.

Comment: Ill update the question

Comment: To get the compiler to allow your cast you have to go through `object`: `return (T)(object)this;`, this is **probably** not what you want though as you're using generics (which is compile-time type safety) but doing it using runtime casting (the compiler is unable to verify that the cast will actually work).

Comment: And `public T ChainableMethod()` does not satisfy the interface requirements, the type in the method declaration **has** to be `IBaseInterface`, so when you've added enough bits and bobs to make the base class compile, your `DerivedClass` won't compile because it doesn't have `ChainableMethod` with the right signature.

Comment: Don't type code without IDE. It don't even compile. Members in interfaces cannot have access modifiers. There is missing `;'. There is extra `n` before `{`. You cannot cast `this` to `T`...

Comment: I of course write code with an IDE, I just changed it a bit to allow for more a concise answer. Did not pan out properly I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working, your code was full of syntax errors:

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
    IBaseInterface ChainableMethod();
}

public abstract class AbstractClassThatHelps : IBaseInterface
{
    public IBaseInterface ChainableMethod()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public interface IDerived : IBaseInterface
{

}

public class DerivedClass : AbstractClassThatHelps, IDerived
{

}


internal static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        IDerived derived = new DerivedClass();
        derived.ChainableMethod().ChainableMethod();
    }
}
```

---

you could also try this:

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
    IBaseInterface ChainableMethod();
}

public abstract class AbstractClassThatHelps<T> : IBaseInterface where T : class, IBaseInterface
{
    public T ChainableMethod()
    {
        return this as T;
    }

    IBaseInterface IBaseInterface.ChainableMethod()
    {
        return ChainableMethod();
    }

}

public interface IDerived : IBaseInterface
{
    IDerived Hello();
}

public class DerivedClass : AbstractClassThatHelps<IDerived>, IDerived
{
    public IDerived Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        return this;
    }
}


internal static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        AbstractClassThatHelps<IDerived> derived = new DerivedClass();
        derived.ChainableMethod().Hello().ChainableMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: so we still have to implicitly cast new DerivedClass() to IDerived?

Comment: @WiseStrawberry your code in the state as is won't work because your `AbstractClassThatHelps` doesn't implement `IBaseInterface ChainableMethod()`

Comment: your interface would need to be generic too `public interface IBaseInterface<T>` but it wouldn't make sense to put any constraint on it

Comment: Yeah That was sort of the question, I assumed that overwriting it with T (which implements IBaseInterface) it would work. I was wrong.

Comment: that is probably the correct answer in the given question. Thanks.

Comment: you use `IDerived` which implements `IBaseInterface`. So `ChainableMethod` will always return `IBaseInterface`

Comment: @WiseStrawberry see updated answer, might be what you're looking for... but only first call to `ChainableMethod` will be of type `IDerived`

Answer (score 2):

In order for the following code to work `AbstractClassThatHelps<T>` must implement `IBaseInterface`. How can you return `this`, if `this` is not `IBaseInterface`

```
public abstract AbstractClassThatHelps<T> where T: IBaseInterface n{
    public T ChainableMethod(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

Edit: I am not user what this design solves but here is my attempt at what you are trying to achieve→

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
    IBaseInterface ChainableMethod();
}

public abstract class AbstractClassThatHelps<T>:IBaseInterface where T : IBaseInterface{
    public T ChainableMethod()
    {
        IBaseInterface i = this;
        return (T)i.ChainableMethod();
    }

    IBaseInterface IBaseInterface.ChainableMethod()
    {
       return this;
    }
 }

public class Concrete : AbstractClassThatHelps<Concrete>
{
}
```

Comment: Updated the question with a cast.

Comment: @WiseStrawberry, It is still the same `this` is not `T` so therefore you cannot cast it

Comment: How would that work, even *if* `AbstractClassThatHelps` implements `IBaseInterface`? It would still not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an *instance* of `T`, but the *return type* cannot be `T` but must be `IBaseInterface` because that is what the interface requires.

Comment: But it seems strange, Do i Need to tackle this problem with generics in the interface

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem *is* exactly. You need to implement the interface *exactly*, not something that comes close. So your method needs to return `IBaseInterface` as a return type. That has nothing to do with generics and you cannot change that with generics.